# Kendo UI Grid Showing json objects as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I get json objects as [object Object] in Kendo UI Grid, How can i visualize it or is there any way to show a detail view of a cell in a Kendo grid ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see `[object Object]` is because `address` is of type object and you pass it into your cell which will convert it to a *string*. And thus the cell is filled with the string representation of object which in this case is `[object Object]`.

---

**Example 1:**

```js
function formatAddress(address){
    return address.street + ' ' + address.phone;
}

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 20,
        data: createRandomData(50)
    },
    pageable: true,
    height: 430,
    columns: [
        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
        // `formatAddress` will be called from the global variable scope like eval() usually does
        { field: "Address", template: "#= formatAddress(data) #" } 
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

---

**Example 2:** (MVVM)

```
<div id="grid" data-role="grid" data-bind="source: gridSource"
     data-columns='[{field:"FirstName",title:"First Name"}, {field:"LastName",title:"Last Name"}, {field:"Address",template:"#= formatAddress(data) #"}]'>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is that the data is random and I cant predict the columns. I read data from remote and display it on the grid.

Comment: What do you mean by *random*? The cells of grid is random or the fields of `address` object?

Comment: I cant predefine the columns for the grid, also I cant predict whether any cell is string or json object.

Comment: Your scenario seems too odd! Please open new question and share your codes to more help us to solve your problem. by the way I tell you what is wrong with `[object Object]`, which is the question you asked. The **grid with dynamic columns and random data** is another question. You can ask it out of here and check mark this as answer.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I asked another question [kendo-ui-grid-with-dynamic-columns-and-random-data-showing-json-objects-as-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567044/kendo-ui-grid-with-dynamic-columns-and-random-data-showing-json-objects-as-obje) .